# Docker Nginx,php keeps Restarting

Tags: php, linux, docker, docker-compose

[image]I have multiple projects that runs on docker locally.but,in my one of project I come a cross issue where my nginx and php container keeps restart state.

When ,I try to

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-local.yml ps

project2-nginx     nginx -g daemon off;             Restating      0.0.0.0:9443->443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5055->80/tcp
project2-php       ./docker-entrypoint.sh php-fpm   Restating      9000/tcp
```

Solution I tried ,

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-local.yml down
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-local.yml up -d
```

When I power off the machine and logged,this is the issue I faced whenever I want work with this project.